# SQL SERVER 2008 final select command with stored procedure

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

i guess it is trivial to get it done right .

in the screen-shot below each user(userid) has two results (which is a kind of a duplicate)

how can i fix query to get only one result per user

(each user can have 2 sets of "TimeIn" and "TimeOut" activities)

so if given user does have a second "entrance" but did not leave yet 
i need only the first closed entrance/leave +  second entrance/still working

[image]

here is the Stored Procedure

```
    create table #tmp (tId int, UserId int, 
    TimeIn1 smalldatetime, [TimeOut1] smalldatetime, 
    TimeIn2 smalldatetime, [TimeOut2] smalldatetime, tId2 int,
    ActiveDate smalldatetime, ReasonID int, Name nvarchar(100), ReasonType nvarchar(100),
    TotalMins int)

    insert into #tmp (tId, UserId, TimeIn1, TimeOut1, ActiveDate, ReasonID, Name, ReasonType)
    SELECT
    t1.tId, t1.UserId, t1.TimeIn, t1.[TimeOut], t1.ActiveDate, t1.ReasonID, tblCustomers.name,tblTimeReas.ReasonType
    FROM tblTime t1
    inner join tblTimeReas on t1.ReasonID = tblTimeReas.ReasonID
    inner join tblCustomers on t1.UserId=tblCustomers.custID
    where (t1.userid in (select custID from tblCustomers where Classification =35) )
    and (DATEPART(DAY,t1.timein)= DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()))
    and (DATEPART(MONTH,t1.timein)= DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()))
    and (DATEPART(YEAR,t1.timein)= DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))

    update #tmp
    set tId2 = (select top 1 tId from 
    tblTime t2 where (userid in (select custID from tblCustomers where Classification =35)) and DATEDIFF(day,t2.timein,#tmp.timein1)=0
                    and t2.tId>#tmp.tId order by tId asc)


    update #tmp
    set TimeIn2 = (select TimeIn from tblTime where tId=tId2),
        TimeOut2 = (select [TimeOut] from tblTime where tId=tId2)


    update #tmp set TotalMins = (
        isnull(DATEDIFF(minute,timein1,timeout1),0)+
        isnull(DATEDIFF(minute,timein2,timeout2),0)

    )

    select *  from #tmp order by TimeIn1
    drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont know how , i didn't take a course for sql server & databse but this is my final code for 
much flexable filtering

```
    create table #tmp (tId int, UserId int, 
    TimeIn1 smalldatetime, [TimeOut1] smalldatetime, 
    ActiveDate smalldatetime, ReasonID int, Name nvarchar(100), ReasonType nvarchar(100),
    TotalMins int)

    insert into #tmp (tId, UserId, TimeIn1, TimeOut1, ActiveDate, ReasonID, Name, ReasonType)
    SELECT
    t1.tId, t1.UserId, t1.TimeIn, t1.[TimeOut], t1.ActiveDate, t1.ReasonID, tblCustomers.name,tblTimeReas.ReasonType
    FROM tblTime t1
    inner join tblTimeReas on t1.ReasonID = tblTimeReas.ReasonID
    inner join tblCustomers on t1.UserId=tblCustomers.custID
    where (t1.userid in (select custID from tblCustomers where Classification Like '%,35%') )
    and (DATEPART(DAY,t1.timein)= DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()))
    and (DATEPART(MONTH,t1.timein)= DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()))
    and (DATEPART(YEAR,t1.timein)= DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))
    and TimeOut is null


    update #tmp set TotalMins = (
        isnull(DATEDIFF(minute,timein1,GETDATE()),0)
    )

    select *from #tmp  order by TimeIn1 
    drop table #tmp
```